# .NET is trying to load incorrect version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions when running as COM-server

Tags: .net, com

I've installed Microsoft.Graph 4.35 from nuget and all dependencies  are downloaded and installed just fine. My project is using .NET 4.7.2

I'm starting my console application and executes the following code without any problems.

```
    var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appID).
              WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, tenantID).
              Build();
```

So far everything is fine. The same binaries are used as a COM-object installed i GAC (exe, pdb, config). When I'm calling exactly the same method running in the inproc COM server I get an exception (0x80131040) saying that it can't find  Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions, Version=6.18.0.0. In my project references version 6.21 is specified.

Running with process monitor I've noticed that the config-file (where it redirects to the correct version 6.21) is not loaded when I'm using it in COM. It seems that something in Microsoft.Identity.Client is trying  load the incorrect version.

```
Call stack:
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Logger.LoggerHelper.CreateLogger(Guid correlationId, ApplicationConfiguration config)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.ServiceBundle..ctor(ApplicationConfiguration config, Boolean shouldClearCaches)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ClientApplicationBase..ctor(ApplicationConfiguration config)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Pyramid.DotnetUtils.Test() in C:\utv\dotnetutils\DotnetUtils\DotnetUtils.cs:line 37
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear: is your COM object an out-of-proc (exe) server or an in-proc dll server? If it's an in-proc dll server, Is your config file aside the .exe loading this .dll?

Comment: It's an in-proc, but I've tried using an out-of-process COM server with the same result. The config file is in the same directory as the COM-server binary in GAC.

Comment: the config file must be aside the loading exe, like myapp.exe.config, not aside the COM binary dll

Comment: Bulls eye, I added the config with the correct v6.21 entry and also added Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions.dll next to the exe and everything worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for this question and the answer. I don't filly understand why the redirection is needed but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Having suffered through many updates I got to the bottom of this.  We have a solution with 3 DLLs and one EXE.

When we used NuGet to update the version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions in the DLL that actually uses it, it did not update the <dependency> entries in the other projects app.config and so, frustratingly, it kept looking for the old version.